# Caching in kubernetes

Tags: node.js, docker, express, kubernetes

I have a ***NodeJS*** app deployed as docker container and I am using ***Kubernetes*** for orchestration.
The *load balancing* is done by Kubernetes by default.

I want to implement caching for the app.

My Question is:
Is it possible to configure the Kubernetes load balancer Proxy to handle the caching also ?

PS: If not then please suggest what is the Best Practice to handle caching in Kubernetes-Docker environment.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Proxy is not used for caching web pages, a cache server (Redis\Memcached) is used for caching web content. Proxy's job is to re-route requests and LoadBalancer has algorithms that it follows for traffic routing i.e. RoundRobin etc.

For this, you have to add a cache server in your application stack in the form of deployment with persistence storage (depending upon your needs).

Comment: Helm can greatly simplify this for you. You can quickly look at
[this chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/redis) for Redis and look [here](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/memcached) for Memached.

Comment: here it say to use reverse proxy for caching as well as load balancing (last paragraph).....    https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-performance.html#cache-request-results

Comment: Kubernetes native service object load-balancing does not support caching etc. Just like open-source reverse-proxies do like Nginx or HAProxy. You might use a headless service (nginx example (here)[https://www.nginx.com/blog/load-balancing-kubernetes-services-nginx-plus/]) for this. This will bypass kube-proxy DNS attached to the service.

Comment: So there are two solutions to caching in Docker-Kubernetes setup: Either use caching server OR  use Nginx  that can handle both (caching as well as load balancing) ??

Comment: Depending on the business needs what type of caching is required. If you need session caching or database queries in case of wordpress\magento for example, Redis may sounds good. If you need minimal full page cache etc, services like FastCGI cache might be a good fit for you.

Comment: Fine...... I tried implement Cashing Server according to your previous suggestion... Pls take a look at this :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55709971/caching-server-in-docker-container-orchestrated-in-kubernetes