# Caching server in Docker container orchestrated in Kubernetes

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, kubernetes

I want to implement caching server in a docker container and the whole cluster is orchestrated by kubernetes.

Below is the diagram with the data flow.

Is this setup according to the best practices ? 
If not then please suggest the best way.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend:

1. Use Kubernetes Operators or StatefulSets with MongoDB instead of stand-alone MongoDB pod. It is extremely dangerous by putting the MongoDB in a pod without any persistence & replica instance. You can find MongoDB operator [here](https://github.com/operator-framework/awesome-operators).
2. Use a separate cache-server in different pods or deployment with master-slave replication for your application. [Operators](https://github.com/operator-framework/awesome-operators) might help you simplify this.
3. Attach the Load Balancer with the Ingress Controller. We don't treat database pods as applications pods (unless they shared data with each other via external storage service) since they contains data and Service LoadBalancer can forward request to any pod in the deployment object.

This varies depending upon needs and requirements.

Comment: ok ...... will you suggest putting MonogoDB in a container and put it with Account service Container in SAME pod ??

Comment: Nope. The LifeCycle of MongoDB pod should be independent of all other services in the cluster.

Comment: Yes. It's better to also separate it.

Comment: in this demo this guy has kept MongoDB container in pod WITH Account Service Container (see the pic here) : 
 https://dzone.com/articles/microservices-with-kubernetes-and-docker

Comment: Above article uses Minikube, not a production ready K8s cluster. This is what he has written:
"The configuration of highly available Kubernetes cluster is not an easy task to perform"

Comment: Ok .. this is what you said so far::  Everything in kubernetes should be in a Pod and Load balanced (ingress, cache service, app services, databases),... and special care for  databases should be taken by keeping it with Kubernetes Operators in the pod ......... CORRECT ??

Comment: Unit of deployment in Kubernetes is Pod. We must use pods in Kubernetes for deploying softwares. Databases should be in separate pods with their own logic implemented via the help of operators or manually such as sharding, persistence storage, replication etc.